# How To Generate A Unique 4-Digit String

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to generate a (fairly) unique (non auto-incrementing) 4-digit string using the numbers 0 - 9 for each digit using C#.  I can validate uniqueness and generate another number if a dup is found.  I had thought about basing the number somehow on the DateTime object's Ticks property but am having a difficult time putting the pieces together.

Any thoughts or expertise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it doesn't increment itself, how is it going to be unique the second time?

Is what you're saying that you want to generate a random 4-digit string from the set of all possible unused 4-digit strings?

If so, the correct approach is usually to generate all possible 4-digit strings, and shuffle them into a random order.  Then take them in order as you need new ones.

**CLARIFICATION:**  Other answers suggest simply generating a random 4-digit string and leaving it at that.  Presumably you would then check to see whether it was already used, and generate another one if it's used.  This has the potential of having extremely suboptimal performance.  Suppose you have already used 9,999 (all but one) of the possible 4-digit strings ranging from 0000 to 9999.  To generate the last one, this method may take many, many tries.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to have a globally unique value.  The problem is that I want a very short number of digits (say 4 or 5) using only numeric values between 0 - 9 for each.  I'd like something GUID-like in that I'm shooting for a small likelihood of collisions.

Comment: @unknown: Well, the probability of a collision is 1/10000 (at the start) and only gets worse as you use up IDs.  Eventually you'll have a very high probability of collision, and then you'll run out of IDs.

Comment: If it's OK to have collisions, then generate the whole list of 10,000 values, shuffle them, and start handing them out.  Until you use up all 10,000, everyone will have a unique one.  When you get to the end, start over from the beginning again, and the new ones will have 1 collision; etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of all 10000 values, using the short type, and then [shuffle](http://dotnetperls.com/Content/Shuffle-Array.aspx) it.

Comment: This was suggested as the answer to another problem on this site. It's a good suggestion. Create a table of numbers in a random order and every time you need a new random string, pick one from the table and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements. How many of these do you expect to generate? If you just need a couple hundred, you can generate a random number 0 to 9999. If you expect to generate all 10,000 of them, then you should just do something like Earwicker said, and maintain a list of all the unused values.

I'd suggest that you start with the simplest algorithm (pick a random number 1 to 9999), and use it until it's too slow. Then go back and put in Earwicker's.

Answer (score -1):

Generate four random numbers each from 0-9 and then do string concatenation on them.

Answer (score -3):

```
Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
return string.Concat(
    randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, 9),
    randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, 9),
    randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, 9),
    randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, 9));
```